# Transfer buckets from S3 to GCS and reverse as well using python3 without downloading the buckets first?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I know there's the gsutil which im looking into now.
But I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to transfer buckets from aws s3 to gcs and from gcs to s3 without having to download all the data locally from one and then and then re-up it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Google Cloud Transfer Service.

You can follow this tutorial :

[Transferring data from Amazon S3 to Cloud Storage using VPC Service Controls and Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/transferring-data-from-amazon-s3-to-cloud-storage-using-vpc-service-controls-and-storage-transfer-service)

> This tutorial describes how to harden data transfers from Amazon
> Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) to Cloud Storage using Storage
> Transfer Service with a VPC Service Controls perimeter. This tutorial
> is intended for data owners who have data that resides in Amazon S3,
> and who want to process or migrate that data securely to Google Cloud.

Comment: cool thing for one offs. but i need something i can integrate into existing automation using python

Comment: I would recommend to check [Migrating from Amazon S3 to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating), you can perform the job by sending requests using an API